# Android - Firebase data from userid to fragment of bottombar

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm done with my login page and registration page, I can already add new data. My problem is with my profile page and it is part of `roughike` bottom bar. On my profile tab which is a fragment. I want to display the full name of the user who is currently logged in. My problem is that with my current code it is force closing the app.

Here's the code:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView userfullName;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    DatabaseReference databaseProfile;

    public ProfileFragment() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        databaseProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid);

        databaseProfile.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String fullname = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue();
                userfullName.setText(fullname);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Update:
Here is the logs.

```
07-10 17:26:59.773 31429-31429/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.lightupstudio.friendler, PID: 31429
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.lightupstudio.friendler.fragment.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:51)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6139)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: did you getting any error?

Comment: please attach your log

Comment: @Upendra I'm really sorry but where can I find the logs?

Comment: if you are using android studio than you can see "android monitor" at bottom or you can get from menu view => tool window => android monitor. for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR6E1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey you have to set rules in your firebase database..

this will set you database to publicly so you will not get an error about authentication..

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

this will set you database to access to only authenticate user by firebase authentication so you will not get an error about authentication..

```
{ 
  "rules": { 
      "users": { 
          "$uid": { 
                ".read": "$uid === auth.uid", 
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid" 
           } 
       } 
    } 
 }
```

for more details refer firebase documantation..

[Check this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: If I set it to public. My database will not be secured anymore. I wanted to have a database that is secured.

Comment: than you can use firebase authentication.. and set rules `{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}`  By this rule only your auth user can access data

Comment: Okay. I will try this later when I get home. Thank you

Comment: Hi so I don't get a force close. but after a few seconds it force closes with this new error on logs.

    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: ohhh. nevermind :) it worked like a charm now! :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an firebase user instance like this to get current user

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```